# Only PHPCS functions in profiler

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, phpcodesniffer, xdebug-profiler

I'm using PHPStorn, XDEBUG and PHP code sniffer on El Capitan.
I'm trying to profile a WordPress theme.
When I run the profiler, I can not find any of my functions in the profiler output.

All I see if PHP_CodeSniffer related functions. What am I doing wrong?
This is my first time trying to use a profile, I'm not even sure if I'm asking the right question.

Thank you for your help.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cv69tt1et658oia/cachegrind.out.1036?dl=0

[image: PHP Profiler output]

Comment: For me it looks like: 1) You have PHPCS integration enabled (so it checks your currently edited file) 2) PHPCS is running at the same time when you trying to do your profiling .. so xdebug captures this data. I suggest disable PHPCS integration for now.. or somehow configure it so it does not use your ordinary php.ini file (where you have xdebug enabled)

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue. User running apache did not have permission to write to xdebug.profiler_output_dir.

I should have realized I was making some stupid mistake when I couldn't find anything questions related to the problem. Hope it helps someone :)